# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, custom-list, wss-3.0

When I click to open any custom List in SharePoint 2007 root site, I receive this error:

```
An error occurred during the processing of . Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.
```

Similarly, when i try to create a new List, i also get the same error. But when i browse back, I see that list successfully creates.

The assembly `'Microsoft.Office.Server'` is there in GAC and in Web.config as well.
I googled but i could not find any solution. Let me know if anyone know the solution of this error?
After modifying web.config, Now i am getting this error:

[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: Try to enable the Fusion log to get the details of which assembly was not found. See these links: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Furthermore, you can see the Windows logs as well as SharePoint ULS logs for errors related to this issue, or create a simple copnsole application / PowerShell script that invokes a method of an object from the 'Microsoft.Office.Server' assembly, to check if the assembly can be really loaded, and not corrupted.